# Вопрос по Java script SetTimeOut и Drug Drop

Tags: javascript, slider, settimeout

Добрый день!
Я сделала слайдер, идея такова при наведение он переставал двигаться, если фокус убираем слайдер дальше листается. При нажатие я могу менять картинки.
Проблема в том что при наведение слайдер похож на эпилептика, не могу понять в чем причина. Почему его так трясет.

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
console.log(ul);
let li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
let counter = 0;
let position = 0;
let timer;

function hi(){
  if(counter < li.length){
    position = position + 300;
    counter++;
  } else {
    counter = 0;
    position = 0;
  }
 
  ul.style.marginLeft= -position + 'px';
  console.log(position);
  timer = setTimeout(hi,2000);
}

hi();

container.onmousedown = function(e) {
  console.log('hi');
  var coords = getCoords(ul);
  var shiftX = e.pageX - coords.left;
  
  //var shiftY = e.pageY - coords.top;
  function moveAt(e) {
    ul.style.marginLeft = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    //ul.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + 'px';
  }
  
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveAt(e);
  };

  ul.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    ul.onmouseup = null;
  };
}

ul.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
  
  
function getCoords(elem) {   // кроме IE8-
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset
  };
}

ul.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){clearTimeout(timer)});
ul.addEventListener("mouseout", hi, false);
```

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul{
  width: 9999px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
}
img{
  width: 288px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="ul">
    <li> <img src='https://xn--46-mlclk1bdi.xn--p1ai/image/cache/data/catalog02/1184-350x350.png' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://xn--i1abbnckbmcl9fb.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8/414762/pril8.jpg' /></li>
    <li><img src='https://xn--46-mlclk1bdi.xn--p1ai/image/cache/data/catalog02/1176-350x350.png' /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Как я понял ваш код страдает из за `document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveAt(e);
  };`, Можете объяснить зачем оно там написано?

Comment: просто суть задания в том что б при зажатой клавиши мыши я могла листать слайд. В лево или в право, для этого я использую onmousemove. https://learn.javascript.ru/drag-and-drop
что то подобное как здесь хочу сделать, только с условием что это будет слайдер карусель.

Comment: Но вы не листаете, а просто перетаскиваете, это как бы не одно и то же.

Comment: В строке `ul.addEventListener....`  -  `mouseover` поменяйте на `mouseenter`, а `mouseout` поменяйте на `mouseleave` - эпилепсия прекратится

Comment: Спасибо и вправду помогло не много! Дмытрык

Answer (score 1):

Вот исправленный вариант вашего кода.

Изменения были в конце скрипта. Вместо `mouseover - mouseout` надо поставить `mouseenter - mouseleave` чтобы не сработало всплытие события, и таймер не запускался несколько раз (смотря куда мышку навели `между img-li и ul`).

```
ul.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){clearTimeout(timer)});
ul.addEventListener("mouseleave", hi, false);
```

И сейчас уже нет `эпилепсий` у вашего слайдера.

```js
let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
let li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
let container = document.querySelector('.container')
let counter = 0;
let position = 0;
let timer;

function hi(){
  if(counter < li.length){
    position = position + 300;
    counter++;
  } else {
    counter = 0;
    position = 0;
  }
 
  ul.style.marginLeft= -position + 'px';
  timer = setTimeout(hi,2000);
}

hi();

container.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var coords = getCoords(ul);
  var shiftX = e.pageX - coords.left;
  
  //var shiftY = e.pageY - coords.top;
  function moveAt(e) {
    ul.style.marginLeft = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    //ul.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + 'px';
  }
  
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveAt(e);
  };

  ul.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    ul.onmouseup = null;
  };
}

ul.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};
  
  
function getCoords(elem) {   // кроме IE8-
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset
  };
}

ul.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(){clearTimeout(timer)});
ul.addEventListener("mouseleave", hi, false);
```

```css
.container{
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul{
  width: 9999px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
}
img{
  width: 288px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="ul">
    <li> <img src='https://xn--46-mlclk1bdi.xn--p1ai/image/cache/data/catalog02/1184-350x350.png' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://xn--i1abbnckbmcl9fb.xn--p1ai/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8/414762/pril8.jpg' /></li>
    <li><img src='https://xn--46-mlclk1bdi.xn--p1ai/image/cache/data/catalog02/1176-350x350.png' /></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```